# how to know the cell which has the different shape in a given column

Tags: python, pandas

How to know the cell which has the different shape in a given column or the whole dataset?

I am encountering a problem that in some places of my data the cell has multiple numbers like (1,2) or [1,2], instead of only one number (only one number is desired. )

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1,2,3,4, (4,5), [5,6,7]], 'column2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

then I get

```
     column1  column2
0          1        1
1          2        2
2          3        3
3          4        4
4     (4, 5)        5
5  [5, 6, 7]        6
```

(The above is just an example. For my real case, the data is imported from CSV, so the `type` of each cell should be `np.float` or sth)

How can I spot the cells where there is more than one number?

Comment: Loop through them and print the ones that have more than one number?

Comment: @JohnGordon really not efficient to loop though data frame.

Comment: I assume this is a data cleaning exercise and would only be performed a few times, until the data is cleaned, so trying for efficiency seems like wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
df[df.column1.str.len() > 1]
```

Comment: What if he has 20 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `dtypes`. Columns that contain only one number in all cells will hold number dtypes, such as `np.float64` or `np.int64`.

Mixed cells will hold `object` dtype.

```
df.dtypes == np.object

column1     True
column2    False
dtype: bool
```

Then you can `apply` `len` using `str` accessor. Since this operation can't be vectorized, at least pre-screening columns will reduce amount of work

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.object].apply(lambda s: s.str.len() > 1)

    column1
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   True
5   True
```

If you *know* your cells will only contain `np.nan`, lists and integers, and you want just spot columns that have lists, just checking the `dtype` will do.